# PHP Ajax Success

Tags: php, html, jquery

I'm making an ajax call in jquery to a php script. But what does the php script need to return for the success/error handler in ajax to fire. So here's the ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        data: $this.serialize(),
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Scripts/script.php", 
        success: function() { 
            alert("script was successful");
        },
        error: function() { 
            alert("script was unsuccessful");
        }
    });
```

So there are a few things the php script can return such as:

```
return 0, 1
return true, false
return "true", "false"
echo "true", "false
```

Which one fires the ajax success/error calls?

Comment: To make it fail, send an error header with [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As long as the server side script sends HTTP status code 200 it will always fire the `success` callback. The response doesn't matter at all. Only the status code. In all examples you have shown you are sending HTTP status code 200 => the success callback will always trigger.

You could force the status code to something different than 200 using the [`http_response_code`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) function.

As an alternative you could have your PHP script return some information and then inside the success function test the value that was returned by your script to know whether some server side processing has failed or not:

```
$.ajax({
    data: $this.serialize(),
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Scripts/script.php", 
    success: function(result) { 
        if (result == 'true') {
            alert("script was successful");
        } else {
            alert("script was unsuccessful");
        }
    },
    error: function() { 
        alert("something very bad went wrong => there's a bug in the script");
    }
});
```

Now your script could echo `true` or `false`.

If you want to send complex objects you could send them as JSON using the [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function and setting the HTTP Content-Type header to `application/json` using the [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.

Comment: There are no errors in your script => HTTP status code 200. You could force the HTTP status code using the `http_response_code` function.

Comment: so there is no way to use one of the four options above to tell ajax that the script was unsuccessful?

Comment: Of course that there is => you could set the HTTP status code to something different than 200. Or inside the success callback you could test the response returned by the PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

Succes executes on a request completed with no errors on `XMLHTTPRequest`, doesn't matter what you are returning as a result. There is another `complete` callback, which executes on your AJAX script complete, doen't matter if you have XMLHTTPRequest errors.

Comment: The script updates someone's password so if something went wrong (like whatever the user typed for current password was not correct) then I want to display `password was not changed` or something. How does ajax know that the php script is terminating unsuccessfully

Comment: Return false, and thema's have an if-else statement in tour succeshandler. @CharlieYabben

Comment: You should pass a variable in your result saying that your postporcessor (php script probably) isn't updated sucessfully your database. This should be checked on `success` callback. If your postprocessor returns 'true' for success, just in success callback check success: `function(r) {if (r == 'true') { ...} ... }`